# An error in Generate javadoc in Android Studio

Tags: java, android, android-studio, javadoc

I'm working with Android Studio Arctic Fox 11.0.10 on MacOS Big Sur 11.5.2.
I'm trying to run Generate javadoc and I get the following errors:

/Users/.../sdk/src/main/java/datos_health/com/sdk/app/fragments/GlucoseWeeklyPagerAdapter.java:3: error: package android.os does not exist
import android.os.Bundle;
^

/Users/.../sdk/src/main/java/datos_health/com/sdk/app/fragments/BaseHistoryPagerFragmentAdapter.java:3: error: package android.view does not exist
import android.view.ViewGroup;
^

/Users/.../sdk/src/main/java/datos_health/com/sdk/app/fragments/BaseHistoryPagerFragmentAdapter.java:36: error: cannot find symbol
public void destroyItem(@NonNull ViewGroup container, int position, @NonNull Object object) {
^

symbol:   class ViewGroup
location: class BaseHistoryPagerFragmentAdapter

and so on....

I tried many solutions from other questions I saw here but nothing worked. These are things I tried:

1. Run with InteliJ - got the same errors and no docs were created
2. Run javadoc in command line - same result
3. Run on a simpler Android app code - same result
4. Add -bootclasspath /Users/.../Library/Android/sdk/platforms/android-30/android.jar - got this error: option --boot-class-path not allowed with target 11
5. Add -sourcepath /Users/.../Library/Android/sdk/platforms/android-30/android.jar - still with the same result
6. Add -classpath /Users/.../Library/Android/sdk/platforms/android-30/android.jar - got these errors instead:

/Users/.../Library/Android/sdk/sources/android-30/android/content/res/Resources.java:44: error: package android.compat.annotation does not exist
import android.compat.annotation.UnsupportedAppUsage;
^

/Users/.../Library/Android/sdk/sources/android-30/android/content/pm/ActivityInfo.java:21: error: package android.compat.annotation does not exist
import android.compat.annotation.UnsupportedAppUsage;

and so on...
^

7. Change JDK to Emebedded JDK - same result

I am at a loss :( Can someone help me?